# Generate two HTML tables side by side from Java

Tags: java, html

I need to print the output of two tables side by side in HTML using JAVA. But they are not printed side by side. I am using this code:

```
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(strFilePath,true); //the true will append the new data
    fw.write("<h1>"+name+"</h1>");
    fw.write("<table float='left' border='1' BORDERCOLOR=Black  width='50%' height='47'>");
    fw.write("<tr>");
    fw.write("<td width='24%' bgcolor='#CCCCFF'><b><font color='#000000' face='Tahoma' size='2'>Environment</font></b></td>");
    fw.write("<td width='24%' bgcolor='#CCCCFF'><b><font color='#000000' face='Tahoma' size='2'>Account</font></b></td>");
    fw.write("<td width='23%' bgcolor='#CCCCFF'><b><font color='#000000' face='Tahoma' size='2'>COUNT</font></b></td>");
    fw.write("<td width='18%' bgcolor='#CCCCFF' align='center'><b><font color='#000000' face='Tahoma' size='2'>Frequency</font></b></td>");
    fw.write("</tr>");
    fw.close();
```

Comment: Use JSP, JSTL, HTML and CSS - not java

Comment: Why dont you model your query in such a way, that the output you get from your sql seems like one table output, hence it will be easier to print it out. 

Also please give more details of your problem, its kind of difficult to understand what data you are trying to display.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all - **mainly because** you have only posted 1 row of 1 table!  Usually, by the way, the best way to make "Two Tables" appear "Side by Side" is to have a **super-table** (outer-table - usually with just one row) that has it's **left-column** as **Table 1** and then it's **right-column** as **Table 2.**  - I, personally, cannot identify from your question what you would want to place in Table 1 and what you would want in Table 2.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML/CSS you need to give the first table float: left; and the second table margin-left

For Example

```css
table{
 border: solid;
}

#one{
  float: left;
}
#two{
 /* margin has to be atleast the width of #one */
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table id="one">
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="two">
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```